# Alias method and pass static argument too

Tags: python

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to easily alias a method (without creating another method) but pass a static argument too?  An example (from how we would normally alias the object - but it obviously doesn't work) to demonstrate what I mean.

```
# Short and to the point
# Normal: alias = method
alias = method("static", arguments)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from functools import partial
alias = partial(method, 'static')
```

or, slower but without imports:

```
alias = lambda *args, **kwargs: method('static', *args, **kwargs)
```

[partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is for exactly this purpose; the `lambda` method is a little more flexible if you need to interleave predefined and changing arguments.